# CakePHP 2.1 loggedIn user in views

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.1. So I am looking for getting loggedIn user in views. How to get the logged user in views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `$this->Auth->loggedIn()` in your view. If it doesn't work then you have to use
`$this->Auth->user('id')`.

For example;

```
if($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
  // then do something
}
```

**or:**

```
if($this->Auth->user('id')) {
  // then do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user

or here:

http://api20.cakephp.org/class/auth-component#method-AuthComponentuser

Comment: Ya i checked that, but in CakePHP 2.1 loggedIn() method added. So i don't know how to use that?

Comment: `loggedIn()` just checks if a user is logged in and returns `true` or `false`. Use `AuthComponent::user('fieldname')` to access their information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the current logged in user details to all views. it will be better to put the logic in the layout file rather than putting the code in all view files.

to get the current logged in user details you can use `$this->Auth->user`

Lets say if you want to display the current loged in user name you can use `echo $this->Auth->user('user_name');`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Auth Component the user data is also stored in the Session's "Auth.User" key.
So in a view it can be accessed with the **SessionHelper**::read() method:

```
$user = $this->Session->read("Auth.User");
```

Auth.User contains the user record from the database.
Don't forget to include the Session Helper in the $helpers array in your controller.